# Can I sync a Rhythmbox playlist with an mp3 player?

Tags: rhythmbox, sync, mp3-player

I can't sync a Rhythmbox playlist onto my mp3 player, how can I do this?

Comment: You should be able to plug it in, have it recognised by rhythm box, and drag and drop the playlist onto the MP3 player. What MP3 player is it? What exactly happens if you try? Does the MP3 Player ever even appear in Rhythmbox?

Comment: Well its my Mobile phone,yet rhymtbox doesn´t do anything, it doesn´t appear either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mp3 player needs to be mounted first. If the settings of the player are o.k. it should appear as an external medium on the desktop. If not so try mounting from the places menu. More information on how to connect players and phones can be found in the [community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortableDevices).

As soon as your are able to view the file contents on your player with e.g. Nautilus you should - as Adam Thompson already said - be able to easily drag and drop the content of your playlist either to the icon on your desktop or to the opened folder from your player in the Nautilus window.

Answer (score 3):

You can get more information on synchronizing a MP3 player using RhythmBox playlists at the location below. There are some useful scripts there as well. The discussion is at

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1291716

Answer (score 1):

If your device is an MTP device then you may find gMTP a better solution. It has a simple GUI and does not have the option to rip files or anything like that. However, it achieves the job of dragging and dropping files and creating playlists, you can even upload cover art for your mp3. I found this was the best choice for my creative zen v plus.

Answer (score 1):

As Mike S says above, the easiest way is described in:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12475542

It prompts you for all your rhythmbox playlists and lets you pick which ones to sync. Moves the files over. Creates a playlist on the device as well. It is a sync not a copy -- so other music files on your device on the Music folder get removed.

Could not be any easier.

After many hours of searching that did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is from Rhythmbox's "Help Tab": Help Tab >> Contents >> Portable Audio Player Source:
*Portable Audio Player Source
Rhythmbox can detect when an portable audio player is plugged to your computer, and is able to read tracks stored on it. Rhythmbox Music Player should be able to deal with most portable audio players including Apple iPod, MTP players and Mass Storage players.
When you plug in a portable audio player, an icon for the Portable Audio Player is added to the side pane. This source works in the same way as the Library source.
**If Rhythmbox Music Player does not detect your device as a portable audio player, you can create an empty file named .is_audio_player at the top level hierarchy of the filesystem of your player.***