# Sony Walkman NW-WS413 and Rythmebox -> Playlists and songorder

Tags: music, rhythmbox, mp3-player, playlists

I'm using Rhytmebox with above Sony Device. The device is showing up under "devices" in Rhythmbox after creating a file with the name .is_audio_player.

After I have created a playlist in Rhythmbox I select the playlist, mark and copy the whole songtracks and paste them on the walkman inside Rhythmbox. It creates a directory structure as following on the device:

Bandname -> Albums -> Tracks

Unfortunately it won't play the songs in the order I used when creating the playlist.

I already tried to switch the walkman as specified in the [sony manual](http://helpguide.sony.net/dmp/nwws410/v1/en/contents/TP0000880536.html) to "playlist mode", but that mode isn't present (maybe because of the process rhythmbox saves the files on the walkman). I also tried to save the playlist.m3u file to the MUSIC-Folder of my walkman, but the mode is still not present.

I can confirm that Sony told me that the playlist must be in the format .m3u and should be placed inside the MUSIC folder of the walkman.

This is the way to create playlists out of windows with Media Go provided by Sony: https://sony-eur-eu-de-web--eur.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/136682/knowledgebase/1

Can somebody tell me if there is a solution to this?

There's a xml file info.plist in the MAC Folder of the walkman. It's contents are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
    <string>11G63</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>Help Guide Installer</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>HelpGuideInstaller.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>Sony-Corporation.Help-Guide-Installer</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Help Guide Installer</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.2.10080</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>DTCompiler</key>
    <string>com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42</string>
    <key>DTPlatformBuild</key>
    <string>4H127</string>
    <key>DTPlatformVersion</key>
    <string>GM</string>
    <key>DTSDKBuild</key>
    <string>12C37</string>
    <key>DTSDKName</key>
    <string>macosx10.8</string>
    <key>DTXcode</key>
    <string>0460</string>
    <key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
    <string>4H127</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>10.5</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Copyright (C) 2012, 2013 Sony Corporation</string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainMenu</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And there is a file "default-capability.xml" in the main folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<devices>
  <version>3.0</version>
  <device>
    <identification>
      <class>WALKMAN/Standard/AudioOnly</class>
      <model>NW-WS410 Series</model>
      <marketingname>WALKMAN NW-WS410 Series</marketingname>
      <vendor>Sony Corporation</vendor>
      <firmwareversion>1.02</firmwareversion> 
    </identification>
    <storage>
      <type>INTERNAL</type>
      <max-full>90</max-full>
    </storage>
    <audio> 
      <format id="WAV">
        <extension>wav</extension>
      </format>
      <format id="MP3">
        <extension>mp3</extension>
      </format>
      <format id="MP4">
        <extension>mp4</extension>
      </format>
      <format id="3GPP">
        <extension>3gp</extension>
      </format>
      <format id="M4A">
        <extension>m4a</extension>
      </format>
      <format id="Windows Media">
        <extension>wma</extension>
      </format>
    </audio>
    <audio-playlist> 
      <format id="m3u8">
        <extension>m3u</extension>
      </format>
    </audio-playlist>
    <filesystem>
      <path>
        <sound>\Music\</sound>
        <soundsources/>
        <feedsound/> 
      </path>
    </filesystem>
    <drm>
    </drm>
    <SensMe available="false" />
    <Kashipita available="false" />
  </device>
</devices>
```

Comment: Can your run the software on a VM to make a sample playlist, to see what it should look like?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I asked Sony if they can send me a sample playlist, but they can't. It should be in the format .m3u and be placed in the MUSIC folder of the walkman (Rhythmbox technically allows to save .m3u-playlists, but they use absolute paths for tracks and weren't recognized by the walkman so far). I also contacted the Rhythmbox devs over IRC, but they basically said it's my problem (and that their playlist support isn't very good). I wasn't successful to create playlists with another player so far.

Comment: If you have access to windowz: https://sony-eur-eu-de-web--eur.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/136682/knowledgebase/1

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Rhytmebox documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Rhythmbox) there are two kind of Playlist definitions as following.

You may need to have an ***Static Playlist*** and make sure *Shuffling* is **off** on Playlist.

> **Static Playlists**
>
> Static Playlists are playlists containing songs manually added from
>   the Library by the user.
>
> Creating a New Static Playlist
>
> 1. Press CTRL+N or select Music > Playlist > New Playlist
> 2. Type the name for the new playlist and press Enter
> 3. Drag and drop songs from the Library onto the playlist's name in the left pane. You may also add songs to the playlist by selecting
>      which songs in the Library you wish to include, then right click on
>      the selections, select Add to Playlist, and select the playlist to add
>      the songs to. To delete songs from a playlist, select the songs in the
>      playlist, then right click and select delete.
>
> **Automatic Playlists**
>
> Automatic Playlists are playlists that automatically include or
>   exclude songs from the Library based on a user-defined set of
>   criteria.
>
> Creating a New Automatic Playlist
>
> 1. From the Music menu, select Playlist > New Automatic Playlist
> 2. Enter your desired playlist criteria using the drop down menus and text boxes, then select the New button
> 3. Click on the newly created playlist under Playlists in the Side Pane and give the playlist a name
>
> To edit the playlist, either:
>
> 1. Right click on the playlist name and select Edit; or
> 2. Select the playlist, then under the Music menu, select Playlist > Edit

Then try [Changing the playback order documented on Sony HelpGuide page](http://helpguide.sony.net/dmp/nwws410/v1/en/contents/TP0000880536.html) from default playing by *Folder* to your desired *Playlist play* instead.

Please note that unfortunately Playlist should be created by **Media Go**  as it's titled below which is that only available for Windows and OSX. So your expected play by List order cannot be achieved by Rhythmbox Playlists. You can create a Playlist on Windows/OSX if you have or Install Windows in VMware to create your list there and send it to your Walkman device.

> Press and hold the button (1) on the left (L) side of your Walkman for
>   longer than 3 seconds repeatedly. Each time you press and hold the
>   button (1), the playback order changes as follows and voice guidance
>   is heard.
>
> **Folder Mode (Normal)**
>
> Plays songs in the order set in folders. Folders are groups of songs
>   shown in Windows Explorer or the Mac Finder.
>
> **Playlist Mode**
>
> Plays songs in the order set in playlists. Playlists are lists of
>   songs to play back in a desired order created by using software such
>   as Media Go (supplied) or Content Transfer.  If there is no playlist
>   in the memory, you cannot select this mode.
>
> **Album Mode**
>
> Plays songs in the order set in albums. Albums are groups of songs
>   organized based on album information.

Comment: That's not the problem. I have a static playlist with songs already.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried to switch modes on the player today. The problem is that there is no "playlist mode" available on my walkman. Maybe the way I copy the files or the playlist.pls file to my walkman is false. Currently I mark all songs in the playlist and copy and paste them to the device. I also tried to save the playlist inside my music folder on the walkman, but the "playlist mode" is still not present.

Comment: I bet they are using a non-sony-process, there must be a solution for this for linux.

Comment: @empedokles If you have a list which is created in Media Go it's easy to write a script to produce the same format of Playlist with your desired list as those are in .XML format though. also please check my updated answer which you can have a VMware

Comment: I've posted you the contents of the info.plist file I have found on my walkman inside the MAC folder above. I don't have a legitimate windows I could use with VMWare, it's not very practical either. I'd rather switch to mac or win under this circumstances.^^

Comment: Have you changed `playlist.pls` generated by Rhythmbox to `playlist.plist` supported by your Walkman device? I always used Ubuntu for playing but music :D so I don't know how is the format of its Playlist, BUT I can confirm if you have a Playlist which your Walkman device can recognize it to play in Playlist mode, I can write a script to convert Rhythmbox Playlist to be playable in your device : )

Comment: No I haven't, but looked inside, it creates links for my harddrive, like: "NumberOfEntries=16
File1=file:///home/nuc/Musik/Linkin%20Park%20-%20A%20Thousand%20Suns%20ak6103/01%20The%20Requiem.mp3" That can't work or can it?

Comment: I also found this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/17654/can-i-sync-a-rhythmbox-playlist-with-an-mp3-player , but too geeky for me.

Comment: Yes, [surly they must be there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947820/sony-walkman-nw-ws413-and-rythmebox-playlists-and-songorder/951873?noredirect=1#comment1516578_951873) in .XML type Playlist, but the format is important here which your Walkman can recognize it. I only need sample Playlist which your Walkman can pay it either with a few songs info in it.

Comment: Do you have a Win or Mac present? I don't. Is there another player besides rhytmebox which works in conjunction with sony walkman?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64951/discussion-between-afshin-and-empedokles).

Comment: The playlist should be in the format m3u according to Sony.

Comment: Dear, now the only way that you should go on for that is installing _**Media Go**_ on **VM** and create a sample Playlist and then post that Playlist and second Playlist you created in Rhythmbox, then we can compare both Playlists or even you can check with yourself to find the differences where the created Playlist in Media Go was playable with your Walkman device

Comment: I have neither VM nor Windowz. If you have it: https://sony-eur-eu-de-web--eur.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/136682/knowledgebase/1